# How can i generate random char from variable

Tags: c++

I have two char string and they have '-' and '+' sign.

I want to pick a random sign from a variable. So far i tried like this, but it outputs only '+' - sign, how can i make it correct?

```
srand(time(0));
char rand_symb;
char plus = '+';
char minus = '-';
rand_symb = rand() % (plus - minus + 1) + minus;
```

Comment: it is unclear what are you asking.

Comment: Why not use the ternary operator? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:

Comment: Something like `rand_symb = "+-"[rand() % 2];`

Comment: A [`std::bernoulli_distribution`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/bernoulli_distribution) would be my personal choice. Then map the boolean value to a `'+'` or a `'-'`.

Comment: Your formula using `%(plus-minus)+minus` only works if plus and minus are adjacent in the ascii table and minus comes before plus. Both assumptions are wrong.

Comment: `rand_symb = rand() % (plus - minus + 1) + minus;` sorry, but this looks like cargo cult programming to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're choosing between two values, so you need to generate two random values. It's simplest to just generate 0 and 1:

```
int value = rand() % 2;
```

(Yes, rabid purists will tell you that this is doomed, because `rand()` sucks, but it's good enough for what you're currently doing).

Based on that value, pick one of the two characters:

```
char ch = value ? '+' : '-';
```

or, to make the whole thing more compact:

```
char ch = rand() % 2 ? '+' : '-'.
```

Answer (score 5):

You'd better off using C++11 [random generation facilities](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) with a fair coin simulator

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

int main()
{
    std::random_device r;

    std::default_random_engine e1(r());
    std::bernoulli_distribution coin_flip(0.5);
    bool sign = coin_flip(e1);

    std::cout << (sign ? '-' : '+');

}
```

<kbd>[Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9c16d77ab203ea10)</kbd>